# How to check if each element in Prolog list is greater than 0?

Tags: list, recursion, prolog

I have the following Prolog predicate prototype: solution(+InputVector), where InputVector is a list of values of an unknown length.  If all the values in the list are greater than 0, I print out a message.  How do I do this?

Comment: You have already described the solution in your question ...

Comment: I'm new to prolog and my professor isn't the best teacher, so I'm really just kind of guessing and testing. Here's an example of what I've tried so far:

solution([X|Y]) :- X > 0.
solution([_|Y]) :- solution(Y).

Comment: You are not handling the empty list `[]`, and currently your solution will succeed if *any* of the numbers are greater than zero, not if all of them are.

Answer (score 4):

if you are interested to extend your learning to 'higher order' predicates, consider [maplist](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=maplist/2)/2:

```
3 ?- maplist(<(0), [1,2,3]).
true.

4 ?- maplist(<(0),[0,1,2,3]).
false.
```

Answer (score 2):

Try checking if the list is [] or [X|Xs], and act accordingly.

Comment: I'm completely new to prolog, so the syntax itself is completely unfamiliar to me.

Answer (score 1):

You were nearly there. Consider the following (updated thanks to @aBathologist):

```
  1|  solution([X]) :- 
  2|     X > 0, 
  3|     !,
  4|     write_ln('Success!').
  5|  solution([X|Y]) :- 
  6|     X > 0,
  7|     solution(Y).
```

Let's consider how this actually works, line-by-line:

1. Defines the first clause of the predicate `solution/1` which takes a *single-element* list containing `X` as an argument.
2. Tests if item `X` is a number which is `> 0`. If not, the predicate will terminate here and fail. Otherwise, Prolog will continue to the next line.
3. While not strictly necessary, the cut (`!`) here removes the choice-point Prolog would have generated at (1) given that the second clause on line (6) could also have been executed with the input `[X]`, as this is equivalent to `[X|Y]` where `Y` = `[]`. Therefore, this is a so-called 'grue'-cut for efficiency only.
4. As the list `[X]` contains elements all greater than zero, the predicate prints a message and suceeds.
5. Defines the second clause of the predicate `solution/1` which takes a list containing *one or more* items, where `X` is the head of the list, and `Y` is the tail (remainder) of the list (which is itself a list which could be empty: `[]`).
6. Same as line (2).
7. Proceed to recursively test the remainder of the list, `Y`.

Note that the above definition assumes that `solution/1` must only succeed on *non-empty* lists of numbers greater than zero. If you wish to permit this predicate to succeed on empty lists, the implementation can be made even simpler:

```
solution([]) :- 
    write_ln('Success!').
solution([X|Y]) :-
    X > 0, 
    solution(Y).
```

In this version, either one of the two *clauses* of `solution/1` is executed based on the argument: the first handles empty lists, and the second handles non-empty lists of numbers which are greater than zero. A cut (`!`) is not necessary here as the predicate arguments are non-unifiable (`[]` \= `[X|Y]`) and Prolog will not generate choice-points for any invocation of the first clause.

I hope this has been helpful, and has made some of the semantics of Prolog syntax clearer for you.

Comment: Again, this will fail if the original input list is empty, which may not be intended. Also, it seems cleaner to do it without if-then-else.

Comment: You can exclude the empty list without `->` thus: `solution([Val]) :-  Val > 0 , write_ln('Solved'). solution([Val | Vals]) :-  Val > 0 solution(Vals)`.

Comment: @aBathologist You're right, thank you! I'll update the answer because I like this better, as it simplifies the description (especially against the alternative which assumes the empty list is OK).

Comment: @sharky I'm very glad I could make a useful contribution! I have two questions, just in case you have time to reply: First, I'm quite new to Prolog, and haven't gotten round to exploring cuts, so its use here is still a bit unclear to me, but I've somehow formed the prejudice that it is preferable to avoid them where possible, since they add to the "impurity" of the declarative approach. Is there any truth to this? Second, could you avoid the ambiguity in line 5 with [X, Y | []]?

Comment: @aBathologist While cuts do make a Prolog program impure, in practice (such as for real world Prolog programming) cuts are often essential for efficiency. If you're doing any serious Prolog programming, I'd recommend understanding how and when to use [cuts](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse44) properly. Also, `[X|Y]` != `[X, Y | []]`. The bar `|` in list notation separates the head _element_ (LHS) from the tail _list_ (RHS). In `[X|Y]`, `X` is the head element, and `Y` is a tail list of any length, whereas `[X, Y | []]` denotes a list of length two.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That was a silly mistake of mine with the lists. Not sure what I was thinking! I'll certainly be looking into cuts.

Answer (score 0):

I'd write the predicate like this:

```
all_greater_than_zero([]).
all_greater_than_zero([H|T]) :-
    H > 0,
    all_greater_than_zero(T).
```

I assumed that an empty list was acceptable.  If not, you can remove the first clause.

Comment: If an empty list is _not_ acceptable, how does simply removing the first clause in your example allow OP to 'print a message' as required if all elements are `> 0`?